# Inner Div should be inside outer div

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am looking from structure. My requirement is as below.

1). I am using KENDO UI grid component and content is inside div.

2). Now in that i have a link, on click of link New Div is opening.

Problem here is that inner div height is greater than outer div.

What I want is to have inner div should be set inside outer div and when I scroll the outer div, inner div increase /decrease accordingly.

Point is that inner div should always be inside outer div.

Please suggest.